# set admob size for landscape mode in split viewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, admob, ads, adbannerview

I am trying to add the Ads from google Admob, I have gone through the documentation and found that we can set the custom size for the ads banner.
  I have done it in this way

```
    int Ad_y;
    int iphone_5Hgt = 548;
    int iphoneHgt   = 460;
    int ipadHgt     = 748;
    int widthHere;
    int hgtHere;
    if (!IS_IPad)
    {
        if (IS_IPHONE_5 || IS_HEIGHT_GTE_568)
        {
            Ad_y = iphone_5Hgt-50;
        }
        else
        {
            Ad_y = iphoneHgt-50;
        }
        widthHere = 320;
        hgtHere = 50;
    }
    else
    {
        Ad_y = ipadHgt - 110;
        widthHere = 703;
        hgtHere = 90;
    }

   AdMob = [[GADBannerView alloc]
              initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,
                                      Ad_y,
                                      widthHere,
                                      hgtHere)];
    if (!IS_IPad)
    {
      [AdMob setAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];
    }
    else
    {
        [AdMob setAdSize:GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSizeMake(widthHere, hgtHere))];
    }

    AdMob.delegate = self;
    AdMob.rootViewController = self;
    AdMob.adUnitID = AdMob_ID;     
    GADRequest *request = [[GADRequest alloc] init];
    request.testing = NO;

    [AdMob loadRequest:request];
    [self.view addSubview:adMob];
```

So, in in iPad with split view controller in landscape mode the size of Detail page is 703 so, i Set it  [AdMob setAdSize:GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSizeMake(widthHere, hgtHere))];
But when i receive the Ads from google some ads are of size less then the specified size.
Text ads are of proper size and fits properly,
    [image: it fits the specified rect on landscape mode of Detail page.]
but the ads with Image (i.e banner) are sometimes not fits the rect.
here is the example
    [image: here the banner sticks to left corner of adMobBannerView and size is less then the required ad size.]
   my questions is: is there any way to show only ads whose size fit the specified rect.
OR can I set the center of the received Ads so it can be adjusted properly.